# After while loop exits, contents of the string are being deleted?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, scope, cout

Hey everyone this is my first post so if I make any mistakes, such as not enough info etc, please let me know so I do not make them again.

So my issue is I need to take the contents of a file and then input them into a string, which I have working. However after the while loop ends if I try to use that string outside the while loop and manipulate the contents the string. The string is blank and there seems to be no contents. I determined this by using std::cout lines. I believe this to be a scope issue but I am not sure how to fix it. Below is the code pertaining to the question, any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 std::string str;
 std::ifstream file;

 while(!file.eof()){
 getline(file, str);
 std::cout << str << "";

 }

 file.close();

 std::cout << str << "";

 std::map<std::string, int> map;

 for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i){

   std::string sub = str.substr(i, k);

   std::cout << sub << std::endl;

   map.insert(make_pair(sub, 1));

   }

  std::cout << "" << std::endl;
```

Also, I am trying to chop the string up into size k which is a variable defined in a different part of the code, so I used the substr method in C++, and I believe this is working because when I put it in the while loop I can print out the contents of the file but the format is off and I think that is because of the nature of how the while loop runs, but I am not sure, please correct me if I am wrong or have any misconceptions.

Comment: One obvious mistake that you should not make again is that the shown code fails to meet all the requirements for a [mcve].

Comment: Okay I just read through that documentation and I understand, thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to store the text file into a `std::vector` and then choose what sentence you'd want to manipulate?
Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream file{ "file.txt" };
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    // Store text file in vector
    while (std::getline(file, str)) {
        vec.emplace_back(str);
    }

    // Print out line 2:
    std::cout << vec.at(1) << '\n';

    // Reverse line 2 and print:
    std::string line2 { vec.at(1) };
    std::reverse(begin(line2), end(line2));
    std::cout << line2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I honestly never thought of that, as of right now my program that I am working on is almost done but I will try a vector implementation after for more practice, is there other reasons that a vector is better/ easier than a string in this case?

Comment: @firetiger443 if it's stored in vector, it will let you choose what line of the text file you want to manipulate. Ex. line 4: `vec.at(5)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are only storing one line at a time with `getline(file, str);`. My guess is that the last line of your file is blank, so the last value stored to `str` is blank.

You can concatenate instead of overwriting:

```
std::string temp;
std::string str;
std::ifstream file;

while(!file.eof()){
    getline(file, temp);
    std::cout << str << "";
    str = str + temp;
}
```

Alternatively, add `#include <fstream>` and use:

```
std::ifstream inputStream("myfile.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputStream), 
                (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```

Comment: This worked perfect and that makes sense I never would of guessed that, thank you for the answer!